# Create message with attachment from selected message using Exchange attachment ID

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, office-js

When you iterate through `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`, each [`AttachmentDetails`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/simple-types?product=outlook&version=v1.5) object has `id` as Exchange attachment ID.

I assumed Exchange attachment ID to be the same as `EWS` Id.

I am trying to add an attachment from the current message to a new reply form, which I open with the `displayReplyAllForm` method. I am using the attachment `id` from the original message.

I get the following error:

> There was an error attaching one or more of the attachments. You can close this response and try again in the app.

[image]

The following is the code I am using:

```js
if (item.attachments.length > 0) {
    var attach = item.attachments[1];
    attachments.push({
        'type': 'item',
        'name': attach.name,
        'itemId': attach.id
    });
    closeOutlookCLIDoc(true);
    Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm({
        'htmlBody': '',
        'attachments': attachments
    });
}
```

[image]

Please confirm the `AttachmentDetails.id` from `attachments` object of the message, which is according to documentation: *Exchange attachment ID of the attachment*, is **the same** as `formData.attachments.itemId` from `Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm`, which is according to documentation: *The EWS item id of the attachment. This is a string up to 100 characters.*?

Here is the [guide](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.md) I'm following.

Answer (score 0):

the displayReplyForm API requires an EWS *item* id. What you are getting via the attachments collection is the *attachment* id. In short, we don't have an API that allows you to pass the attachment id over into displayReplyForm API and have that item added as an attachment. You have to either take that attachment and save it as an item in some folder for the user, so that then you can pass its EWS item id, or you have to get the attachment bytes, put them up on a URL and then add a file attachment.